# SQLite SELECT with JOIN to result all relationship data

Tags: t-sql, android-sqlite

I have a db schema and I am quite not so familiar with T-SQL, I know, ORM's ruined me.  Developers :)

This is the schema.

Table1 1 - 1 to three tables (Table2, Table3, Table4) and each Table(2,3,4) 1 - 1 to a Table5.

Graph (try) representation:

```
Table1  1<->1 Table2 1<->1 Table5
        1<->1 Table3 1<->1 Table5
        1<->1 Table4 1<->1 Table5
```

I need a query to retrieve all Table1 records and their corresponding relationship data, Table1,Table2,Table3 and their relationship data to Table5.

Any help appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I actually needed was this:

```
SELECT F.*, DE.Title as EnergyDrinkTitle, DE.[Picture] AS EnergyPicture, DI.Title AS InspDrinkTitle, DR.Title AS RelaxDrinkTitle 
FROM
(Select M.*, E.DescriptionTitle, I.[DescriptionTitle], R.DescriptionTitle, 
E.[DrinkId] as EnergyDrink, I.DrinkId as InspDrink, R.[DrinkId] as RelaxDrink
FROM  [Member] M
LEFT JOIN [Energy] E
    ON M.[_id] = E.[MemberId]
LEFT JOIN [Inspiration] I
    ON M.[_id] = I.[MemberId]
LEFT JOIN [Relax] R
    ON M.[_id] = R.[MemberId]
) AS F JOIN Drink DE ON F.EnergyDrink = DE._id
JOIN Drink DI ON F.InspDrink = DI._id
JOIN Drink DR ON F.RelaxDrink = DR._id
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your full table structure and the column names you should be able to join the tables in a similar manner as this:

```
select *
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2
    on t1.id = t2.id
left join table3 t3
    on t1.id = t3.id
left join table4 t4
    on t1.id = t4.id
left join table5 t5
    on t2.id = t5.id
    or t3.id = t5.id
    or t4.id = t5.id
```